# Cannot commit configuration changes because the file has changed on disk

Tags: asp.net, powershell, iis

I would like to have a powershell script that could create an IIS web site.
but I am getting error

> New-IISSite : Filename:
>   \?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config Error:
>   Cannot commit configuration changes because the file has changed on
>   disk At C:\projects\salonsecretSrc\RegisterWebSite.ps1:38 char:9
>   +         New-IISSite -BindingInformation $strIssBindigFormat -Name $st ...
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-IISSite], FileLoadException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.IIS.Powershell.Commands.NewIISSiteComman

this is my script:

```
$strCurrentPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$strWebSiteFolder = Get-ChildItem (dir $strCurrentPath)
$strWebSiteBindingPath = $strWebSiteFolder.Directory.FullName+"\build\WebSite"
$strCurrentFolderName = $strWebSiteFolder.Directory.Name
$strIssSiteName = "$strCurrentFolderName.local"
$strIssBindigFormat = ":80:$strIssSiteName"

Write-Host "Current Script path: $strCurrentPath"
Write-Host "IIS Web Site phycical path: $strWebSiteBindingPath"
Write-Host "IIS SiteName: $strIssSiteName"
Write-Host "IIS Bindindg Format: $strIssBindigFormat"
Write-Host "Creating App Pool - $strIssSiteName"
        New-WebAppPool -Name $strIssSiteName -Force
        Write-Host "Creating Web Site Pool - $strIssSiteName"
        New-IISSite -BindingInformation $strIssBindigFormat -Name $strIssSiteName -PhysicalPath "$strWebSiteBindingPath" -Force
        Write-Host "Mapping Pull and Web Site - $strIssSiteName"
        Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\$strIssSiteName" -name applicationPool -value $strIssSiteName
        Write-Host "$strIssSiteName WebSite Created"
```

what could be an issue how to solve ?

it could create an web site first time but second time if I remove it manually it will get this error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many different things that can lock the applicationHost.config file and cause powershell commands like `New-IISSite` to fail.

In this case, you mentioned you deleted the site manually so perhaps you still have IIS Manager open and it is locking the file. I suggest closing IIS Manager.

As described in this [blog post on Powershell and IIS](https://octopus.com/blog/iis-powershell#retry-retry-retry), the makers of Octopus Deploy have found that the only reliable solution to the file-locking problem is to wrap any file-altering commands like `New-WebAppPool` in try-catch blocks and retry these operations multiple times. The source code for a function to do this is found in the blog.

Comment: This actually seems to bug-out for me. Where the first time the `New-IISSite` command is ran, it'll complain about the applicationHost config file. Then all subsequent runs it will think the site is already created (but it isn't). Only by refreshing the powershell session this seems to reset.

Answer (score 3):

It seems something really screwy is going on with New-IISSite command.  I ended up dropping back to New-Website (via WebAdmistration module), and all the problems went away.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is the first entry in google about this issue, I will describe my findings to the cause of the error message here. It's maybe not related to OPs issue.

**Example for failing code**

```
Get-IISAppPool
New-WebAppPool -Name TestAppPool
New-IISSite -Name TestSite -PhysicalPath D:\ -BindingInformation *:80:test
```

**Explaination**

If using `Get-IISAppPool` from the [IISAdministration PowerShell Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/?view=windowsserver2022-ps)
followed by `New-WebAppPool` from the [WebAdministration PowerShell Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/webadministration/?view=windowsserver2022-ps),
the command `Get-IISAppPool` will somehow prevent `New-WebAppPool` from closing the `applicationHost.config` file and probably leaves it in an open state.

If we now run `New-IISSite`, we will get the Error:
`New-IISSite : Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config Error: Cannot commit configuration changes because the file has changed on disk`

I was able to reproduce this with other Commands too if followed the order described above:

1. Get-*Cmdlet from **IISAdministration Module**
2. New-*Cmdlet from **WebAdministration Module**
3. New-IISSiteBinding from **IISAdministration Module**

**Prevention of the issue**

To workaround this issue I found two solutions.

1. Remove the **IISAdministration Module** before executing `New-IISSite`
2. Wrap `Get-IISAppPool` and `New-WebAppPool` in `Start-IISCommitDelay` / `Stop-IISCommitDelay`
3. Only use one of the Modules. I decided to only use the IISAdministration Module. It's not in the Microsoft Docs but you can create/delete AppPools with it too using the `Get-IISServerManager` cmdlet as described [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windows-powershell-docs/issues/421#issuecomment-431714951).

**Workaround 1**

```
Get-IISAppPool
New-WebAppPool -Name TestAppPool
Remove-Module IISAdministration
New-IISSite -Name TestSite -PhysicalPath D:\ -BindingInformation *:80:test
```

**Workaround 2**

```
Start-IISCommitDelay
Get-IISAppPool
New-WebAppPool -Name TestAppPool
Stop-IISCommitDelay
New-IISSite -Name TestSite -PhysicalPath D:\ -BindingInformation *:80:test
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `Remove-Module IISAdministration` worked. I tried to do DSC and may have installed that. Did not know these bullshit can conflict with eachother.

Answer (score 2):

The fix for me was to call `Reset-IISServerManager -Confirm:$false` after creating the app pool, before creating the website.

The reason is that the IISAdministration PowerShell module (at least as of now) does not support creating application pools, so that has to be done using the older WebAdministration module. Once that change is made, the IISAdministration module has an old view of the config data, so needs to be reset to include the changes made by the WebAdministration module.

According to the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/reset-iisservermanager?view=windowsserver2022-ps), this command:

> resets the IISAdministration view of the IIS ServerManager object and
> the view of .config file applicationHost.config to the current
> contents of the .config file